# Prevent toddler bed-wetting

Tags: cleaning, personal-care

I have a 3 years old son, my wife is trying to stop him using disposable diaper at night, so sometimes he is bed-wetting now days.

My questions are :

1. Is there a way to reduce or stop him bed-wetting?
2. Is it save to wash a pillow in a washing machine (he sometimes wetting my pillow)?

Comment: This may be a better fit for https://parenting.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I think my 2nd problem fits here.

Comment: The second problem doesn't require a lifehack.  It is off-topic.